# Dynamic task creation using decorators in Airflow 2

Tags: python-decorators, airflow-2.x

I would like to create tasks dynamically in a flow based on the result from another task. Is it somehow possible to do it in the following way ?

I am able to do that by storing data from task in a temporary file and in the next task read it - but I would like to solve this problem using only airflow resources.

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


@task
def extract() -> dict:
   return {"1001": 301.27, "1002": 433.21, "1003": 502.22}


def load_inner(dict_value_fun):
   print("Value is: {}".format(str(dict_value_fun)))


default_args = {
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'retries': 1,
}


@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None,)
def tutorial_taskflow_api_etl():
   order_data = extract()

   for key in order_data:
      @task(task_id='task_key_is_{}'.format(key))
      def load(dict_value: dict, key: str):
         load_inner(dict_value[key])

      order_data >> load(order_data, key)

tutorial_etl_dag = tutorial_taskflow_api_etl()
```

Error message:

```
The key (dict_key_is_{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='extract', dag_id='tutorial_taskflow_api_etl', key='0') }}) has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores exclusively
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that creating dynamic task using airflow resources is not possible because DAG is not a regular Python file that runs in one system process. Airflow environment usually works with a few workers so it can happen that tasks are executed independently on different servers. To be able to create tasks dynamically we have to use external resources like GCS, database or Airflow Variables.

I had to solve my problem using Airflow Variables:
You can see the code here:

```
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import logging
import json


@task
def extract() -> dict:
   return {"1001": 301.27, "1002": 433.21, "1003": 502.22}

@task
def set_variables(val: dict):
    # before running dag we have to set a variable
    variable_val = Variable.get("dynamic_dictionary_variable_value")
    logging.info("current variable value (before change) is " + str(variable_val))

    logging.info("updated value " + str(val))

    # we have to change dict type into string otherwise we get error about wrong quotation
    Variable.set("dynamic_dictionary_variable_value", json.dumps(val))

    variable_val = Variable.get("dynamic_dictionary_variable_value")
    logging.info("current variable value (after change) is " + str(variable_val))


default_args = {
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'retries': 1,
}

@dag(default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(2))
def dynamic_workflow():
    current_directory = Variable.get("dynamic_dictionary_variable_value")
    logging.info("(before) current_directory outside task is " + str(current_directory))

    values_directory = extract()
    return_val = set_variables(values_directory)

    current_directory = Variable.get("dynamic_dictionary_variable_value")
    logging.info("(after) current_directory outside task is " + str(current_directory))

    for key in json.loads(current_directory):
        @task(task_id='dynamic_task_{}'.format(key))
        def load(key_name: str, val: float):
            logging.info("key_name: {}, value: {}".format(key_name, val))

        return_val >> load(key, json.loads(current_directory)[key])

dynamic_workflow_dag = dynamic_workflow()
```

Before running this dag we have to remember to set Airflow Variable dynamic_dictionary_variable_value = {}. In my example I use {"50": 50.505}

DAG at the beginning looks like:
[image]

After execution it looks like:
[image]

Comment: We have to remember that this is for sure not a production solution Especially if we would like to have another task after the group of dynamic tasks. If we increase number of dynamic task they will not be process to the end when the next task starts executing its job - it will not wait for success of parent tasks because doesn't know about them - it will learn after airflow refresh but the it fails.